# Flutter moving point over image

Tags: flutter, image, dart, canvas, move

I want to create a moving point that moves across an image. The picture is drawn on canvas. The point should approach the specified x and y coordinates.Image and point are generated. The point should move to the new specified position every 500ms by a timer.But it only moves when I move the mouse over buttons on the app.

```
class five_og extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() {
    return _five_og();
  }
}

class _five_og extends State<five_og> {
  ui.Image? image;
  Timer? timer;

  void refreshImage() {
    if (i >= xList.length - 1) {
      i = 0;
    }
    ImagePainter(image!);
    i++;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    timer!.cancel();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    loadImage('assets/images/Erdgeschoss.png');
    timer = Timer.periodic(
      Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      (timer) {
        refreshImage();
      },
    );
  }

  Future loadImage(String path) async {
    final data = await rootBundle.load(path);
    final bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    final image = await decodeImageFromList(bytes);
    setState(() {
      this.image = image;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: image == null
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : Container(
                  height: 600,
                  width: 600,
                  child: FittedBox(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: image!.width.toDouble(),
                      height: image!.width.toDouble(),
                      child: CustomPaint(
                        painter: ImagePainter(image!),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                  )
                  ),
    );
  }
}

class ImagePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image image;
  const ImagePainter(this.image);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    //final paint = Paint();

    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset.zero, Paint());

    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 182, 253)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(xList[i], yList[i]), 13, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(ImagePainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```